# I keep getting this error , Data type mismatch in criteria expression. I cannot figure out why

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using Access for my database. The Table Passengers has the following
I cannot seem to find where the problem is. Can someone please help me out

```
Passenger Number(Auto Number)
FirstName (short text)
LastName (short text)
Initials (short text)
ID_number (short text)
Gender (short text)
Date_of_Birth (Date/Time)
Cell_Number (short text)
Street_Number (number)
Street_Name (short text)
Postal_Code  (number)
```

//These are my variables

```
        string name = txtFirstName.Text;
        string surname = textBox3.Text;
        string initials = textBox2.Text;
        string id = textBox6.Text;
        string gender = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string dest = cmbDestination.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string num =textBox9.Text;
        string snum = textBox8.Text;
        string sname = textBox7.Text;
        string pcode = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string date = dateTimePicker1.Text;
```

//Here is my code, It is supposed to add a new record to the Table Passengers, but I keep getting the error

```
        try
            {
               using (OleDbConnection connect = new 
               OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
               Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\Database3.accdb"))
               {

                   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO 
                   Passengers ([FirstName],[LastName],[Initials] , 
                   [ID_number],[Gender],[Date_Of_Birth],[Cell_Number], 
                   [Street_Number], [Street_Name],[Postal_Code]) VALUES 
                   (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", connect);
                    cmd.Connection = connect;

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", name);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", surname);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Initials", initials);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_number", id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", gender);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Of_Birth", date);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cell_Number", num);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Street_Number", snum);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Street_Name", sname);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postal_Code", pcode);


                    connect.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    OleDbDataAdapter adapt = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * 
                    FROM Passengers", connect);
                    MessageBox.Show("Seat successfully booked for 
                    passenger!");
                    Console.Beep(659, 125); Console.Beep(659, 125); 
                    Console.Beep(659, 125);

                    this.Close();
                    connect.Close();


                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: You are sending through everything as a string, obviously all your DB datatypes are not strings

Comment: `Date_Of_Birth` is `Date/Time` and parameter value `date` is of `String` type. That's is one probable reason you are getting this error. Try to convert `dateTimePicker1.Text` to `DateTime` and then pass it as parameter value to the command.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple column value assignment issues in your example code, in this case you're passing `string` values to columns which has either `number` or `date` type which causing data type mismatch exception.

Instead of using `AddWithValue` for all kind of values, you should use `OleDbCommand.Parameters.Add()` to specify proper data types and values like this example:

```
// note: use DateTime.ParseExact for specific date formatting
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date_Of_Birth", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Parse(dateTimePicker1.Text);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Street_Number", OleDbType.Integer).Value = int.Parse(textBox8.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Postal_Code", OleDbType.Integer).Value = int.Parse(comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

**Edit:**

For `DateTimePicker` control, you can use [`Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value?view=netframework-4.7.2) property which has `DateTime` type:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date_Of_Birth", OleDbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
```

Reference: [ADO.NET OLE DB Data Type Mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ole-db-data-type-mappings)